# How to edit the view of "The page has expired due to inactivity" in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.5, When you are using CSRF protection (by default) and you send a post request after long inactivity you'll get this error page (Screenshot).
I'm ok with this error however, I need to change the view/text of this error to match my application style and my language for sure.
Any Ideas in how to edit this view?

[image: Screenshot from Laravel 5.5 error page]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can override the default view by placing a `419.blade.php` file in the `resources/views/errors` folder.

If you're using an editor with global search capabilities, you can search for the error message inside your project. For example, in Visual Studio Code you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search inside the project.

[image]

I use it all the time to find the files which are part of the framework that I need to customize.

More on overriding the error views in this section of the official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#custom-http-error-pages).

Comment: Thank you. I already searched for this error using PhpStorm, But I didn't get any results. however, you solved my problem.

Comment: If this is not enaugh for you - you can add your own exception handler in `app\Exceptions\Handlers.php` as described here: https://hisman.co/article/laravel-csrf-token-mistmatch-exception/

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default view by placing a 419.blade.php file in the resources/views/errors folder.