# Laravel Status in German

Tags: laravel

I want to know if its possible to set some Laravel status in another language.

Sometimes I got this status:

> The page has expired due to inactivity.Please refresh and try again.

The website looks like this:

[image: The website looks like this]

How is it possible to say to Laravel I want all these pages in German?

I searched so many things and I changed these error messages in German but I cant find anything to change websites like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663905/how-to-edit-the-view-of-the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-in-laravel-5-5

Comment: This depends on if you are hoping that the content will translate through some sort of translation vendor library, or if you want to hardcode the German translation yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new HTTP errors views.

```
resources/views/errors
```

This one is 419 error, I think.
[Laravel DOC here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#custom-http-error-pages)